# Displaying java variable on html page

Tags: javascript, java, php, html, css

I really did not want to be posting this, but here I am. It looks like I have been unable to find any way to simply display a java variable in an html doc. I have a feeling this isn't possible and I should be using javascript or something else but I would love it if someone could point me in the right direction.

My Java code is simple and basically just creates a single int that I would like to use in my html doc. For arguments sake let's imagine this:

**JAVA CODE**

```
public class Counter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 24;
    }
}
```

Once again for argument sake

**HTML CODE**

```
<HEAD>
<script src="java/counter.java"></script>
</HEAD>
```

I've looked into things like document.write() and Element.innerHTML but I believe these things are probably associated with Javascript and/or JSP. I'm expecting more of an explanation rather than some simple code since I'm sure I'm going about this wrong. Just want to know how I should create my "counter", whether it be in Javascript or something else. I am using PHP and CSS so I also am also not sure if I should be using those to access my programs final int. First dive in to multi language programming so be gentle. Thanks!

Comment: do you have tried java applets, or jsp?

Comment: I have looked into Java applets as well but to be honest I didn't want to jump in without knowing whether or not that would suite my needs. As for JSP I have no experience and am in the same boat, really just want to know the best way to go about this before I research something new. @ChannaJayamuni

Comment: You need to work with javascript

Comment: If I work with Javascript would I need to work with JSP aswell? Just need to know what I should be googling and I'll get right at it. Thanks! @SajithaNilan

Comment: No. javascript can work with any scripts like HTML, PHP, JSP, ASP

Comment: Okay, seeing JSP as similar to things like HTML, PHP, and ASP helps me make sense of this. Appreciate the help! @SajithaNilan

Comment: I think you are familier with Java, So try to go with JSP  :D

Answer (score 4):

you have to write your variable like this

"<%= variable name here %>"

in your JSP file

Comment: Okay so there's one problem...not using JSP. I'll for sure look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i have to mention is **"YOU CANNOT DO IT WITHOUT AN APPLET OR JAVA WEB SERVER"** with live updates of your variable.

1. If you don't want to live update your web page, you can create a .html file with java and open it through your browser.
2. If you are free to use another programming option you can use javascript instead of java.
3. If you need both live update of variable and java as programming language, you should use one of java applets and jsp page with server. I recommend to use jsp since it is highly available of resources.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, lets clear smth here. Java is an interpreting language, which means you cannot run java without calling its executable interpreter or a web container or application deployment platform.

If you run java code, very firstly  you should compile it and get compiled byte code. This would be a ".class" file. Then if you want to run it as standalone application then you should use platform dependent interpreter. For Windows OS, it is "java.exe", for linux platforms it would be "java" executable. For WEB applications there are some sort of containers like Jetty, Tomcat which can run class files and compile (JSP files not java).

Lets assume that, you are using Tomcat with your web application. Then with your app, you can run your code with JSP file or with async call it is difficult in your case.

Find a very simple JSP tutorial and try howto run your code.

Comment: Okay perfect. Really appreciate the explanation. Kinda figured what I needed was more of an understanding then some lines of code. I'll be looking into JSP and Javascript for most of tomorrow. For now it's time to sleep on all of this. Thanks a bunch!